# Copy files in persistent volume kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jar, persistent-volumes

I want to add or copy files into persistent volume and then use  it in container using volume mount ?any help

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Please refer K8S documentation for PV, SC and PVC https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#claims-as-volumes

Comment: I have checked this doc but couldn't find any solution . I have created PV and PVC and now i have to copy a folder from my local machine to that persistent volume

Answer (score 5):

Once PVC/PV are created (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), there are number of possible solutions.

For specific question, options 1 and 2 will suffice. Listing more for reference, however this list does not try to be complete.

1. Simplest and native, `kubectl cp`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp
2. `rsync` - still quite simple, but also robust. Recommended for a task (both of below options were tested)

   - TO pod: https://serverfault.com/questions/741670/rsync-files-to-a-kubernetes-pod
   - FROM pod: https://cybercyber.org/using-rsync-to-copy-files-to-and-from-a-kubernetes-pod.html
3. `tar`, but incremental: https://www.freshleafmedia.co.uk/blog/incrementally-copying-rsyncing-files-from-a-kubernetes-pod
4. Tools for synchronisation, backup, etc

- For example, https://github.com/backube/volsync